# ARC and sending messages to objects without specifying the class at compile time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, clang

I'm trying to understand where ARC is getting the method signature information to do its job.
In the following code, I send a message to the parent of this object without specifying its class.
If I don't typecast the parent ivar, the compiler issues a warning.
If I typecast it to id, then the program works and no warnings are issued. The same is true
if I use `performSelector:withObject:`

If the method on the parent is different to `userSelected:` then the only thing that works
is `performSelector` (while issuing a warning).

As I understand it, ARC is getting the method signature from the object the call to self.parent is made. Is this correct? Can you avoid telling ARC what class an object is if the method signature exists in the object from which the message is being sent?

```
- (void)userSelected:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.parent respondsToSelector:@selector(userSelected:)]) {

        //1: This fails with error (no visible interface).
        [self.parent userSelected:self];
        //2: This line works without warnings.
        [(id)self.parent userSelected:self];
        //3: This line also works
        [self.parent performSelector:@selector(userSelected:)
                          withObject:self];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wil Shipley is correct in his deleted answer when saying that this is not ARC related.

The warning you are getting is about the static type of the receiver (`self.parent`) and the compiler trying to help you to prevent sending messages to an object that doesn't respond to this selector. In other words: `self.parent`'s class does not contain a declaration of `userSelected:`.

But the compiler does know a method named `userSelected:` (in some other class or category) because it lets you send this message to an object without static type information. It's a little like the C language lets you use a void pointer for any type of pointer.

So, again, all of that is not ARC related and would not change when switching to MRC.

**Edit:**

Yes, when sending messages to `id` the compiler considers any visible @interface and @protocol to find the selector's declaration. "Visible" in this case means any imported header, be it custom, framework or prefix. The method declaration is needed mainly to get type information of the parameters.

Note that ARC behavior is only affected in very rare scenarios (when the declaration includes information about ownership semantics, like `objc_method_family` and similar).

If the compiler finds conflicting declarations it emits an error. When trying to compile ...

```
[(id)nil type];
```

... you'll get ...

```
> error: multiple methods named 'type' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes
```

... plus a couple of differing declarations in UIKit, Foundation and other frameworks.

Comment: but if the method being called on self.parent is userSelected: there is no warning nor failure. It works correctly. So my question is this: does the compiler look for method signatures in both the existing file as well as the appropriate class file (for self.parent)? Can ARC (or well, the compiler) look for selectors across all project files? What is the method in this file would have had the same selector but different parameter?